# Matching String regex with Optional (foobar)

Tags: regex

I have this data:

```
/blabla/blabla (abs,def)

/yxz
```

I use this regex

```
(.*)(?:\(([^$]*)\))?\n
```

But it doesn't work, and i don't know whats wrong.

I need the first "directory" information and optional the Information in "()".

Comment: Explain what you actually want the regex to match. Also, be more clear about the variety of data. Does the "blabla" bit ever consist of non-alphanumeric characters other than forward-slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, maybe? `([^(\n]+)(?:\(([^)]*)\))?`

Answer (score 1):

This regex extracts the first directory in group 1 and anything between the () optionally:

```
/([^/]*)(?:\((.*?)\)|.)*
```

Let me know if this works or need some assistance.

```
Match 1:    /blabla/blabla (abs,def)         0      24
Group 1:    blabla       1       6
Group 2:    abs,def     16       7
Match 2:    /yxz        28       4
Group 1:    yxz     29       3
Group 2 did not participate in the match
```

edit for quick joe

Comment: i need the first "directory" information and optional the Information in "()".

Comment: @buckley, I would undo my downvote, but the site won't let me unless you edit your answer.

Comment: That's better. Moral of the story: refresh page _before_ casting vote.

Answer (score 1):

Try using some online regexp matcher (ex: http://www.rubular.com/ ) to test by your own. Many of them has the match highlight function, and you can refine your regex by them